# Knockout binding multiple observable arrays

Tags: knockout.js

I am looking for a bit of advice on what would be the best way to handle two arrays of objects (one being a subset of another) and checkboxes.

Basically I have this [fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/iiminov/88rafcfk/10/) as an example. The code I am actually working with is full on with database support and everything.

I am trying to achieve a binding between of checkboxes between a full set of members and a selected subset of members.

```
// member model
var Member = function(item) {
    var self = this;

    self.id = item.id;
    self.avatar = item.avatar;
    self.name = item.name;
};
```

Basically I have the following model with three properties which I will not be modifying.

```
// card model
var Card = function (item) {
    var self = this;

    self.cardId = item.id;
    self.title = ko.observable(item.title);
    self.description = ko.observable(item.description);
    self.contentItemId = ko.observable(item.contentItemId);
    self.dueDate = ko.observable("");
    self.comments = ko.observable(0);
    self.openItems = ko.observable(0);
    self.completedItems = ko.observable(0);
    self.labels = ko.observable("");
    self.members = ko.observable("");
    ...
};
```

And this is where the magic needs to happen. By definition database stores **Members** as a comma separated list e.g. (",1,2,3,4,5"). I already written code to retrieve full list of members and individual members to populate

```
    self.members = ko.observable([]);
```

What I am thinking is to update individual **Card** with appropriate **Member** as card is being initialised for the first time.

So far so good!

In the view I want to trigger **self.editMembers** function which by definition should hide all content in **cardLeftColumn** (well maybe apart from Cards title) and display full list (table) of members with two additional buttons to **Save** and to **Close**.

So far so good!?

My main problem right now, hrm, how do I word this, checkboxes. I want checkboxes to get checked for those users in **Card.members** dataset when I call **self.editMembers**. Just to clarify **Card.members** will contain a subset of **Board.members** array (which isn't defined yet).

If you take a look at [fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/iiminov/88rafcfk/10/) you will notice at the moment I binded a list of **Card.members** on table row, and that because I am not sure how to achieve what I am looking to get done.

I am also not sure how to retrieve a list of selected members (which I would then need to save in the database) on **Save** action.

Another thing I am unsure of is how to bind **edit** link/button on card to be visible to members that are assigned to specific card (**Card.members**). Any advice in this depart would come in handy but not a show stopper. I haven't quite pinned down what way I am going to determine which user is viewing the page. But it is very like to be **users id**. In other words I probably end up comparing page viewers' **user id** to **Card.members.id** to determine if **edit** link/button is to be available to them.

And just to summarise I am looking for a bit of advice with the following:
1. how to link checkboxes between two datasets
2. how to get at list of checked members at **Save** action
3. and a bit of advice of how to hide **edit** link/button from users that are not assigned to the card

Thank you for taking the time to read my post.

#### Update 1

Added fiddler link to my example that I was referring too.

So just to recap @Haridarshan has provided some interesting suggestions below.

Last night I fetched a list of all members from database and added them as

```
self.members = ko.observable([]);
```

on BoardViewModel. That is just before I initialise lists with their card I fetched and initialised a list of members.

I also fetched individual members assigned to each card and initialised `self.members = ko.observable([]);` on each card.

Effectively I was to bind all members array in BoardViewModel on the table but I ended getting an error that my BoardViewModel.members are undefined in the current context which would be true because the table that I was trying to bind too would be in the context of Card.members.

I need to doodle a bit on this with provided suggestion from @Haridarshan. So we shall see where I got from here.

#### Update 2

Using some of the advice by @Haridarshan I managed to bind **edit** link/button using `if: function(ref)` - [Click me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27036260/how-reference-this-in-knockout-view/27037033#27037033). Not 100% working yet but its almost there.

I've extended Module model with `self.isChecked = ko.observable(false);` and now I can get at members that were selected. Which means I can send new list of assigned members to the database.

That still leaves the issue of binding all members to the table. I tried `$root.members` which didn't give me result I was after. But even if it did I am still unsure how I am going to cross check that list to **Card.members**. I might end up modifying **self.editMembers** function to do that.

Comment: You haven't provided the fiddle link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood **self.members** observable contains the **Members model**. So, you can map your data to self.members through mapping. Assuming **self.members is an observable array** and **data** is the response data of Member Details from database.

```
self.members(jQuery.map(data, function (item) {
    return new Member(item);
}));
```

In html, using foreach binding, you display all member list with checkbox. So, you need to add checkbox observable in Member model.

```
var Member = function(item){
    var self = this;

    self.id = item.id;
    self.avatar = item.avatar;
    self.name = item.name;
    self.isChecked = ko.observable(false);
    self.isVisible = ko.observable(<conditional statement whether to hide or show>);
}
```

and assuming you're showing the data like this

```
<!--ko foreach: members-->
    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="visible: isVisible, checked: isChecked" />
    <div data-bind="text: id"></div>
    <div data-bind="text: avatar"></div>
    <div data-bind="text: name"></div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Now, you want to have editing functionality for each member, so the edit method should be bind to Members model

```
var Member = function(item){
    var self = this;

    self.id = item.id;
    self.avatar = item.avatar;
    self.name = item.name;
    self.isChecked = ko.observable(false);
    self.isVisible = ko.observable(<conditional statement whether to hide or show>);

    self.editMember = function(data){
        // here you will do the edit functionality 
    }
}
```

further, for hiding edit button/link from users that are not assigned to the card, you can add visible observable to the Member model and in checkbox binding you add the visible binding.

For **Save** action, since you need the list of entire member who are checked  that method should be added to Item Model.

```
var Card = function (item) {
    var self = this;
    ...
    ...
    self.Save = function(data){
        //using ko.utils.arrayForEach, loop through all members and check for isChecked observable
        // and do whatever you want to do.
    }
}
```

Comment: Very interesting suggestion. My apologies I was in bit of a hurry when I posted this and didn't realise until now that I haven't actually linked fiddler I was referring too.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. I was able to put some of this to good use and learn something new.