# How reference this in knockout view

Tags: knockout.js, reference

Greetings all I have a very simple question for you today.

I have this markup (view):

```
<div class="cards" data-bind="sortable: { data: cards, afterMove: cardMoved }">
    <div class="card">
        <div><span data-bind="text: title"></span></div>
        <div class="dnnRight" data-bind="if: firstMatch(this, id)">
            <a href="#" class="dnnSecondaryAction" data-bind="click: $root.openCard"><%= LocalizeString("EditBtn") %></a>
            <a href="#" class="dnnSecondaryAction" data-bind="click: $parent.removeCard"><%= LocalizeString("DeleteBtn") %></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Basically it has a `foreach` data-binding on `card` model. I have written a simple enough function to find first matching element based on `id` parameter which lives inside card model definition. But I need to be able to refer to the card in question in order to access it's observable parameters within my function.

How can I reference individual card? `this` keyword isn't working for me.

#### Update 1

As I pointed out I've been trying everything from knockout documentation [Binding context](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html) but most of the time I end up with an error.

```
Error: Unable to process binding "foreach: function (){return lists }" Message: Unable to process binding "sortable: function (){return { data:cards,afterMove:cardMoved} }" Message: Unable to process binding "if: function (){return firstMatch($data,2) }" Message: Cannot write a value to a ko.computed unless you specify a 'write' option. If you wish to read the current value, don't pass any parameters.
```

#### Update 2

Actually it might help if I adjust my function to just take `id` as a reference becuase when `if` calls `firstMatch()` I should be able to access `members` ìn the current context using `this.property`

```
    //identify the first matching item by id
    self.firstMatch = ko.computed(function (id) {
        var search = false;
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.members, function (member) {
            if (member.id == id) {
                search = true;
            }
        });
        return search;
    });
```

Comment: Can you try `$data` instead

Comment: I have been trying everything from knockout documentation [Binding context](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html) with not much luck. But I am sure I am getting closer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether **self.members()** have values or not. If it is null it will not go in the loop

Comment: I have ``self.members = ko.observable([]);`` initialised as empty array (just before members initialised from database) which means it can be empty (if members weren't added at some point) but not null. Hence it should skip foreach if array is empty but when its not it should give me access to individual objects so I can perform cross reference check.

Comment: If self.members() will have values, then it will surely go inside the loop but if its empty or null, it will skip. 

Providing jsfiddle will be a great help to resolve your problem

Comment: ko.observableArray() is an array of observables where as ko.observable([]) is a normal observable in which you have passed the array.

In ko.observableArray(), you can directly push the items like you do in array e.g. self.members.push(values);
But in ko.observable([]), you push values in the array stored in observable e.g. self.members().push(values);

Comment: Thank you for good explanation @Haridarshan. It certainly puts into perspective for me.

Answer (score 0):

And that seem to have fixed my issue. I was just over complicating stuff as usual.

Updated view():

```
<div class="cards" data-bind="sortable: { data: cards, afterMove: cardMoved }">
    <div class="card">
        <div><span data-bind="text: title"></span></div>
        <div class="dnnRight" data-bind="if: firstMatch(id)">
            <a href="#" class="dnnSecondaryAction" data-bind="click: $root.openCard"><%= LocalizeString("EditBtn") %></a>
            <a href="#" class="dnnSecondaryAction" data-bind="click: $parent.removeCard"><%= LocalizeString("DeleteBtn") %></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Updated model():

```
    //identify the first matching item by id
    self.firstMatch = function (id) {
        console.log('firstmatch()');
        var search = false;
        console.log('search: ', search);
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.members(), function (member) {
            console.log('member.id', member.id);
            if (member.id == id) {
                search = true;
            }
        });
        console.log('search: ', search);
        return search;
    };
```

Now I just need to figure out why I am not getting inside `ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.members(), function (member) {...});` and I should be golden.

#### Update 1

As @Haridarshan suggested to check if the `self.members()` is null or empty this is what I am getting:

```
self.members() == ""    => true
self.members() == null  => false

self.members() === ""   => false
self.members() === null => false
```

And sure enough `self.members().length` returns a 0.

Hrm...

#### Update 2

Looking at [dosumentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html) whats the difference between:

```
self.members = ko.observableArray();
```

and

```
self.members = ko.observable([]);
```

if any?

#### Update 3

Why it didn't hit me earlier. The reason for `self.members` array showing 0 and not going into loop is because the call to fetch individual member was done asynchronously. Meaning ajax did its job and the rest of the code happily run along. But that presented a problem of not having members in the array at the time of checking.

So this problem is now solved thanks to everyones input.